# Looking for a well used opensource .net WMS server that can show raster layers

Tags: wms

We covered a large area with a plane and have all the images with georeferences avalible also. I would like to provide the images taken as a WMS and not knowing much about gis still, there are alot of options out there. I hope someone here can direct me to a good candidate to start developing against.

I found something called MapArround and a .net example using it but that was only showing shape files. If anyone has an example in MapArround leveraging custom images that would be great.

Otherwise, then any example of leverage our custom taken photos. We already have software that sticth images together and having overlap so basicly for every request we have the images needed to be provided. I took the time to look at the WMS specification and know we could implement the requests our self but if we can save time but just providing an extension into some already opensource wms solution that is preferable.

Comment: Have found SharpMap and MapAround sofar

Comment: What about MapWindow http://www.mapwindow.org/